# Hiding dropdown menu on hover issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can see that this question has been asked a bit although I've found no solution that fixes my specific problem.

I have a sub menu within a menu that doesn't work as intended, it simply needs to be shown when hovered over and then when it's not hovered over, hide the sub menu.

Right now I can hover over the menu item but then when I got to select the next option it disappears.

I don't know where I'm going wrong, I know it's a simple feature yet it's driving me mad! here's my working below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.subhover').on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.subhover').on("mouseleave", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  display: hidden;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown menu-btn">
  <a id=t estmanage class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-database fa-lg "></i> Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="btn_addnew" href="#">Create Audit</a></li>
    <li><a href="store_departments_list.php">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="store_product_management2.php">Products</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="subhover" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Data Entry <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="labour_costs.php"> Labour Costs </a></li>
        <li><a href="purchases_list.php"> Purchases </a></li>
        <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#salesModal">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="waste_list.php"> Wastage </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Forgive me for the formatting of the HTML part, can't get it to look like how it displays on my editor!

Comment: It would be of help if  you can create a jsfiddle or running code snippet, as we don't know if you are using any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using CSS-Only. Just take a look at my solution:

```css
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  display: none;
}

.subhover:hover ~ .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown menu-btn">
  <a id=t estmanage class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-database fa-lg "></i> Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="btn_addnew" href="#">Create Audit</a></li>
    <li><a href="store_departments_list.php">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="store_product_management2.php">Products</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="subhover" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Data Entry <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="labour_costs.php"> Labour Costs </a></li>
        <li><a href="purchases_list.php"> Purchases </a></li>
        <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#salesModal">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="waste_list.php"> Wastage </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

> **And in this fiddle, both dropdowns are working together:** https://jsfiddle.net/thau2g9j/13/

Comment: Hey J. Sadi thanks for the quick answer - I understand how this is working on the Manage tab although I would need this on the Data Entry part which I just can't seem to wrap my head around for some unknown reason! Is there any way you can show the example on the Data Entry part?

Comment: Hey, i've already updated my solution to the data entry part.

Comment: I've also added a fiddle where both dropdowns are working together. :)

Comment: Still having the same issue J. Sadi! I removed the JS part of my code and the Data Entry part wont open up anymore. It's strange because your fiddle works perfectly, although when copied over exactly it still isn't working as intended...

Comment: Nevermind all good, just me being silly, cheers J. Sadi! I think this'll be good to work with. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One more thing actually J. Sadi - I've noticed that the menu now appears directly below instead of to the right, what's the reasoning for that if you don't mind explaining? thanks!

Comment: could you provide a fiddle? in my fiddle they are not appearing directly below, or they do and i don't unterstand what you mean. :D

Comment: Once again no problem, got that working haha - you've helped a lot J. Sadi, thanks again - enjoy your weekend!

Comment: I got issue in dropdown menu hide on hovering
note - hover on category
see in codepen - https://codepen.io/vishal590/pen/RwxKodr

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are executing same lines of code on `mouseover` and `mouseleave`. The below code is not required. Comment and check, if that should suffice you requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.subhover').on("mouseleave", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Below is the running code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.subhover').on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

//$(document).ready(function() {
 // $('.dropdown-submenu a.subhover').on("mouseleave", function(e) {
   // $(this).next('ul').toggle();
   // e.stopPropagation();
   // e.preventDefault();
 // });
//});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  display: hidden;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown menu-btn">
  <a id=t estmanage class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-database fa-lg "></i> Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="btn_addnew" href="#">Create Audit</a></li>
    <li><a href="store_departments_list.php">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="store_product_management2.php">Products</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="subhover" tabindex="-1" href="#"> Data Entry <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="labour_costs.php"> Labour Costs </a></li>
        <li><a href="purchases_list.php"> Purchases </a></li>
        <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#salesModal">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="waste_list.php"> Wastage </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Wini San, this is the same way I had it before, I need the menu to disappear when I've left the selection. So if I hover over Data Entry it shows the menus but if I move away, it hides the menus. It only hides if I go back over Data Entry.